# How to get Youtube channel banner using Youtube API?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm working on a PHP project that need to get Youtube channel banner (or cover photo), avatar and uploaded videos from a specific Username.

For avatar and videos, I use:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels?q=Username&alt=json&v=2

But for the channel banner, I have searched on the Internet but no luck. Anyone here can help me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it with V3 of the API. You'll need the actual channel ID (not just the username), and then do a request to:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&id={CHANNEL-ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

(Note you'll also need an API key from the cloud console).

If you don't have the channel ID, you can get it from the username with this call:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&forUsername={USERNAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: For those looking for this, this API endpoint has now been deprecated. details are here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#september-9,-2020 , but there aren't many details besides that the endpoint is deprecated. I know of no other way to get the image, unfortunately.

Comment: it works, but I got a picture not in the same resolution on the YouTube channel but smaller, so I can't stretch it on my website

Comment: @СтасРябцев the default resolution you receive is in most cases not the highest resolution available. You can e.g. add '=s600' to the URL and will receive an image with longest side 600px. Or you add '=w1920' and get the banner with width 1920px. There are also parameters for cropping and post-processing. idk whether they are documented though...

Comment: @Стас Рябцев - it doesnt seem to work any more. How did you get channel banner after they have deprecated this?