# Youtube - url source to channel banner WITHOUT API

Tags: url, youtube, wget

Trying to write a tool to grab YT information, and I'm starting out with the banner image. Usually I use Inspect Element and it will tell me the source, however on a channel like [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4rqhyiTs7XyuODcECvuiiQ) I see no such URL. Id like to be able to, in my script, use something like wget and have it grab the image.

My hopes are to NOT have to rely on the YT API to save users from having to go through that.

I'm just trying to see if there is a URL scheme to retrieve a channel's banner. Thanks

---

In case it's better for me to add it all in one question, here it goes: I'd like to be able to grab all of the following w/o the API:

- user avatar (highest quality)
- [video watermark](https://cdn-backlinko.pressidium.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/ht4-hr3-branding-watermark.png) (also in highest qual.)
- [channel description](https://www.youtube.com/user/scottthewoz/about)
- related urls (at the top right, usually a channel's twitter account, main website, etc.)

Comment: All other questions I saw required the API

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64306688/7243748