# How to extract image link using Jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape 2 images from a YouTube channel, the profile picture, and the banner without using the official YouTube API.

This is where I'm trying to get the images from:

```
view-source:https://www.youtube.com/c/CyberpunkGame
```

The profile picture can be found in this field:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnj_luY7M1Ps1THwD3jjpBGCK3IQD7xSl8VN8TQLlw=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj">
```

And the banner can be found here:

```
":2276,"height":376},{"url":"https://yt3.ggpht.com/1rRhEmeV6_SNWKl2pPhdT6csoTeJBBpuspsKmQbPlLzASMvbMY8beVUxbLqVqHLGeTrhXR08=w2560-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj"
```

I want to extract only both URLs of the image images.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code from this class [YoutubeChannelProfileImage.java](https://github.com/spapapan/UtubeVideoThumbnails/blob/master/YoutubeChannelProfileImage.java)

Example code:

```
String url = "www.youtube.com/...";
YoutubeChannelProfileImage.getYoutubeChannelProfileImage(url);
```

If you found it useful, please leave a star :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to get channel's banner and profile images not video thumbnail.

Comment: @IlyasseSalama I am sorry, wrong class :P I added a new one and edited my post. Check it out.

Comment: It works for profile picture, but the header return nothing. Check the GitHub code of header.

Comment: @IlyasseSalama The URL has to be in this format to work: https://www.youtube.com/channel/<channelid>

Comment: What about youtube.com/c/channelid or youtube.com/user/channelid

Comment: I just run the code actually using your url "https://www.youtube.com/c/CyberpunkGame" and it worked.

Comment: Worked, something was missing

Comment: @Student - is there a javascript solution to this?

Comment: @Toniq I don't have a javascript solution but regex expressions are universal so it won't be difficult to write this in javascript.