# How to get Youtube channel banner using Youtube API with the same resolution?

Tags: image, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, banner

I made a request:
[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&id={CHANNEL-ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&id=%7BCHANNEL-ID%7D&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)
to YouTube to get a banner like in this thread:
[How to get Youtube channel banner using Youtube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793167/how-to-get-youtube-channel-banner-using-youtube-api/21793559).

However, I received it at a lower resolution (512x288) than on the YouTube channel. How to get it in exactly the same resolution as on the YouTube channel?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the YouTube Data API's official revision history document:

> [**September 9, 2020**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#september-9,-2020)
>
> **Note:** This is a deprecation announcement.
>
> This update covers the following API changes. All changes will go into effect on or after 9 September 2020, the date of this announcement. With that in mind, developers should no longer rely on any of the API features listed below.
>
> - The following API resources, methods, parameters, and resource properties are deprecated immediately and will stop working on or after the date of this announcement:
>
>   - The following channel resource properties:
>
>     [...]
>
>     - The `brandingSettings.image` object and all of its child properties
>
>     [...]

Later, the assertion quoted above got [officially confirmed by Google staff](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172473713#comment2) (on Nov 19, 2020):

> **Status: *Won't Fix (Infeasible)***
>
> You can no longer see the brandingSettings.image, please see the revision history below as reference for this behavior. So this is working as intended.
>
> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#september-9,-2020

Consequently, Google discontinued providing the info you're needing, while specifying no official alternative. This is unfortunate, but a fact.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, YouTube now gives a low-quality 512x288 image in the API, but there is a way to get a high-resolution image like on YouTube: After you have received the url of a low-resolution image, add the following parameter to this image at the very end: `=w2120-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj` For example, you received such a picture: `https://yt3.ggpht.com/AQ3VxGthGB5kNbrlaQz2BdRpfeTrwfkVev_5aSW7vE91TbT7Zcrm57NsYTn5BoEuGNIB6ZAMUK4`

We add our parameter and get a high-resolution picture `https://yt3.ggpht.com/AQ3VxGthGB5kNbrlaQz2BdRpfeTrwfkVev_5aSW7vE91TbT7Zcrm57NsYTn5BoEuGNIB6ZAMUK4=w2120-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj`

I am not sure that in the future the parameters for obtaining high quality will not change, but at the moment it works!

Comment: @Syscall add translate

Answer (score 0):

To complete [@inf1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183316) answer, here are all available parameters:

```
banner:

=w1060-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w1138-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w1707-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w2120-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w2276-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w2560-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj

tvBanner:

=w320-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w854-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w1280-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w1920-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w2120-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj

mobileBanner:

=w320-fcrop64=1,32b75a57cd48a5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w640-fcrop64=1,32b75a57cd48a5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w960-fcrop64=1,32b75a57cd48a5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w1280-fcrop64=1,32b75a57cd48a5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
=w1440-fcrop64=1,32b75a57cd48a5a8-k-c0xffffffff-no-nd-rj
```